# firebase firestore return wrong data for collection query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore db to get collection by the name of the collections array it seems that Firestore return wrong results from another collection when I print the results are not form the collection is db.collection(collectionName).get() method. I didn't see error in the loop also in returned value from collections.Any clue where can be the problem.

```
   private String[] collections = {"appetizers", "breakfast", "indian", "lunch", "noodles", "salad", "trending"};
    private int n = 0;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        db.collection(collections[i])
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            resultList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                                System.out.println(collections[DashBoardActivity.this.n] + " collection " + (String) data.get("data_name"));

                            }
                            DashBoardActivity.this.recipesMap.put(collections[DashBoardActivity.this.n], resultList);
                            DashBoardActivity.this.n++;

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Task not successful fire");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Edit: adding screenshot of the database
[image]

Comment: Add your firestore data to the question please.

Comment: I need to export it from Firestore or just the data i receive in the app

Comment: I just check I can't export it from firestore

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I added database screenshot. Is returning different results each time

Comment: @mikegrep In that case, what is the result that you get, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result is to put the results for each collection in hashmap with collection name as string and arraylist of results for this collection but I recive the data for another collection not this i call with get()

Answer (score 0):

If all data are recived, I think it just because order differentce between every time you run `.get()`, Consider using `ref.orderBy(/* field */);` to get constant order.

Comment: This does not help me since I need to grab the collection by name and not by the fields  inside.I fix the issue as a make a List of Strings with the collections names and call if for each loop.